# Modal/dialog box

Tags: 7, javascript

This sound like a really dumb question, but for the life of me I cannot find something that works.

I want to trigger a modal/dialog box for some basic content.  Its just HTML, not the login page or password reset or webform, or an image.  I just want to pop some content into the modal box.

Whats the best way to do this?  I ideally I would be able to control the dimensions of the window.

Comment: If you don't want to use any modules, you can achieve it by using CSS only - [HTML / CSS Popup div on text click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064987/html-css-popup-div-on-text-click#answer-19065024) - [Full screen Overlay using CSS only](http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/fulloverlay.html#)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lightbox module](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2) to achieve that, but note if you want to open a modal content you need to use `rel="lightframe"` as an attribute for the `<a>` tag.

Also don't forget the Library of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Overlay Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/overlay_paths) module

> This is a simple module that enables site builders to use the built-in Overlay for non-admin pages.
>
> This means that you can use the overlay for doing popups without adding yet more javascript libraries to your site.
>
> This module provides a simple UI for defining paths to appear in the overlay, but developers can use it to define paths too, see the overlay_paths.api.php file in the module for details.